# Disable/Hide buttons in view table based on role

Tags: views, 8, users, commerce

Is there any way to disable/hide certains buttons/links in a view table based on role?

I want to display admin buttons/links in drupal commerce for all the orders if the user/role is admin, customer buttons/links for customers and vendor buttons/links for vendors.

**Image for reference :** 
[image]

Comment: As long as those links were generated "the Drupal way", Drupal, Views in this case, will automatically hide those if the user does not have permission to access that route/path. Thus, you have a permission issue.

Comment: but if they do not have permission to access certain route/path, the links will still be displayed. right ?

Comment: How did you exactly go about adding those links?

Comment: `but if they do not have permission to access certain route/path, the links will still be displayed. right ?` No, if they don't have access, they should be hidden if you added them by creating a custom views field. But if you hard coded them, ex: `<a href="/some/path/edit{{id}}">Edit</a>` then they will still show up because Drupal doesn't know about them since they weren't added utilizing the Drupal/Views API.

Comment: I added 3 columns : edit, View & Delete  and then excluded them from display.. Then added custom text column and using replacement patterns merged the 3 columns onto one.

Comment: Thought so... doing it like that won't get Drupal to auto hide them. You need to programmatically create a custom views field and use the [link class](https://agaric.coop/blog/creating-links-code-drupal-8) to create links.

Comment: Okay. thank you. it might take a day for me to learn this since I had no idea about this. i'll try it and reply back if there's any error/issue